# Could a very light humanoid creature throw a javelin?

Tags: biology, physics, weapons

My story has a creature that is vaguely humanoid in shape and lives on an Earth-like planet. However, the creature is smaller (dingo-sized) and only weighs around 35 pounds.

Like humans, these creatures evolve precise throwing ability for hunting, specifically for larger prey. However, due to their dramatically lower body mass, launching a large projectile with accuracy seems like it would be more difficult.

Could it stand to reason that this creature could throw a wooden javelin with similar speed/momentum to a human despite having less muscle mass? Would some kind of biological energy-storing/spring-loaded system be useful?

For what it’s worth, it possesses hollow bones, which could decrease the inertia of the throwing arm itself (or increase risk of self-injury). Also, while the creature can run faster than a human (useful for Olympic-style throwing), I would prefer if there were other factors improving its ability to throw hard.

Comment: Should the throwing action remain limited to the arm(s)?

Comment: They could use a cantrip similar to Aztecs' "atlatl", that thing was mentioned around this board.

Comment: @Lemming The throwing action doesn’t need to stay limited to the arms. I’m already assuming it would be a full-body type of movement.

Comment: There are [tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spear-thrower) that give mechanical advantage to a thrower (obviously humans use them as well, with more base strength). But throwing applies extreme tension load to the shaft of the humerus, so those hollow boans might be the real issue here.

Answer (score 10):

The Javelin is made for human strength and size, specifically to be thrown as far as a human warrior can throw it. If it were twice as long and twice the diameter, it would weigh 8 times as much, and be thrown a much shorter distance. As it stands, it is the balance chosen between force and distance, because we want to kill our targets (particularly animals that don't throw back) while being as far from them as possible.

> In international competition, men throw a javelin between 2.6 and 2.7 m (8 ft 6 in and 8 ft 10 in) in length and 800 g (28 oz) in weight, and women throw a javelin between 2.2 and 2.3 m (7 ft 3 in and 7 ft 7 in) in length and 600 g (21 oz) in weight.

As you can see, the women reduce the weight by 25%, and the length by 15%, to maximize their distance given their (on average) lesser force and body mass. In fact, female athletes on average develop 25% less muscle mass than men.

Your little people would do the same. At 1/4 the height of a human, they'd be likely be 18" tall, and perhaps 40% the weight of a human So instead of 165 pounds, 66 pounds. Their muscle mass would be proportional, so their best javelin would likely be 320g (11.2 oz). The javelins tend to be 1.5 times the average height; so you might want to make them 27" (2' 3") for manageability, and adjust the diameter to make the weight appropriate.

At this point, you are talking about a thick arrow. If you want distance, I'd consider a foot bow; from a seated position, draw the bow with an arrow with both hands, using your feet to press the bow away. You can put straps on the bow handle to insert the feet; . Then the power of their whole body, arms legs and back are involved, and you should get quite a distance on the arrow, and these are not much harder to aim than a traditional bow.

See this site: https://archeryhistorian.com/footbow/

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Humans solved this by using a force multiplier such as a sling for rocks, or spear thrower for large darts.

I can't hit a car reliably with a spear thrower at any distance, but I can throw further with it than I could unaided. And I can throw a rock over 100mph without overstraining using a sling again and again. Which I couldn't do once without one and would probably injure myself trying repeatedly.

Answer (score 4):

/Would some kind of biological energy-storing/spring-loaded system be useful?/

**Oh yes.**

[image: throw javelin like discus]

https://www.sbnation.com/secret-base/21522919/javelin-world-record-throw-felix-erauzquin-basque-technique

Your javelin throwers whirl around, accumulating kinetic energy as the rotational energy of their bodies and throwing the javelin like a hammer or discus.  I would have thought the linked article was a joke but the video looks real.  People threw the javelin 50% farther with this technique, which was banned because of its wild inaccuracy and danger to spectators.

--
Not only do your dingo people (btw upvote just for the [proud dingo people!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=egpOhBgNmYg)) whirl around before throwing, they do it in teams of 2 or 3 or sometimes more.  Crew served javelins of cooperative whirling dingofolk can handle javelins heavier than a single human can throw, and throw them farther.  One of the crew members is actually thrown herself with the javelin and she completes the throw while airborne, the force propelling her backwards into the arms of her crew.

Dingo peligroso!